# Python Module Importing Issues

Tags: python, module, directory, importerror

I run Windows 7, and I can import built-in modules, but when I save my own script and try to import it in IDLE, I get an error saying that the module doesn't exist.

I use the Python text editor found by clicking "File" and "New Window" from the Python Shell. I save it as a .py file within a Module folder I created within the Python directory. However, whenever i type import module_name in IDLE, it says that the module doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong, or not doing? I've tried import module_name, import module_name.py, python module_name, python module_name.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python uses PYTHONPATH environment variable to define a list of folders which should be looked at when importing modules.  Most likely your folder is not PYTHONPATH

Comment: So then how do I make the folder PYTHONPATH, and then how do I import the module from that folder? Also, how do I find out the exact directory of that folder?

Sorry for the noob questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the module's path to sys.path variable:

```
import sys
```

`sys.path.append(pathToModule)`

Comment: you need to find out it by yourself :) usually it's easy to save the module to the predefined location and add this location to the sys.path variable.

e.g. if module is in c:\my_modules
sys.path.append(r"c:\my_modules")

Comment: What does the r do in front of the path? Is that raw text?

Comment: Ah, just figured it out! I thought I was saving my module as a .py file when I wasn't! Stupid me  :/

Answer (score 0):

The way to import your own modules is to place the file in the directory of your program and use the following code:

```
from Module import *
```

where Module is the name of your module.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing the module you created? When I create a module, I do the following:

1. Create a folder in the lib\sitepackages folder in your python folder ex: myModules
2. Save a blank python file named **init**.py in this folder. The file does not have to contain any syntax. Later on, you can set module requirements in this file if you wish.
3. Save your module into this folder ex: myGamesModule.py

In idle (or whichever python connected IDE you use) type:

**from myModules import myGamesModule**
or 
**from myModules import myGamesModule as myGmMod**

That should import your module and then you can call the classes etc
ex myGmMod.Player()

I am sure that this is correct, as I have just done it and it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

add a blank file called **init**.py to the module folder. this tells python that the folder is a package and allows you to import from it
the file name should be

```
__init__.py
```

stackoverflow keeps formatting my answers and messing thngs up. Thats 2 underscores on each side ofv the word init