# python Import module from a different directory structure

Tags: python, import, module, directory, importerror

```
     common/src/validation/file1.py
```

In the common/src/validation/ and common/src/ folder "*_init_*" is defined.

```
     common/test/validation/file2.py
     common/test/validation/case/file3.py
```

In file2.py and file3.py, I want to import class from file1.py.

Im giving the following line in file2.py and file3.py.:

```
      from file1 import class1
```

I currently get error:

```
      #ImportError: No module named file1
```

what should be the sys.path.append ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: import a file from a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/python-import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

You can basically just change PYTHONPATH to `common` and run from there. Then reference all import paths in relation to that.

like so: (assuming you are in common and your main is in file3.py)

`PYTHONPATH=. python test/validation/case/file3.py`

Make sure to have `__init__.py` files in any directory you import (the content of this file doesn't matter)

I usually like putting in the root of every project a `run.sh` file with some version of this line (pointing to wherever my main func is) in it.

It will usually contain a simple something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
source some_env/bin/activate # start the relevant environment if you have one
PYTHONPATH=. python src/main.py # set PYTHONPATH and run
deactivate # exit the relevant environment if started one
```

Another option is to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488548/python-module-importing-issues?rq=1) but is't not as elegant.

Comment: IS there a way without using the PYTHONPATH ? I would like to use sys.path.append...

Comment: check the link in the end of the answer.. [here it is again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488548/python-module-importing-issues?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a file from a folder you should have a file named

```
__init__.py
```

in that folder (it could also be a blank file).